# What coal mining towns in Austria were in common migration paths for Slovenians?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, austria, migration

I have a marriage in Austria on January 10, 1898 between Jožefina Gregorčič most likely born in [Veliki Cernik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veliki_Cirnik), Slovenia on February 24, 1874 and coal miner Alois Kovač born in Austria on June 30, 1872.  They have a [marriage commemorative souvenir](https://www.wikitree.com/photo/jpg/KovaC-18) written in german:
[image]

which translates as:

> [groom] Alois Kowatsch [bride] Josefa Kowatsch, maiden name Gregortschitsch married 10. January 1898 in Austria.

Her brother was perhaps married in the mining town of [Trbovlje](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trbovlje) in 1897.

Their first son was born on January, 24 1900 in [Gladbeck, Coesfeld, North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladbeck) where Alois was a coal miner before immigrating to the United States in 1904.

I'm trying to get some ideas of possible towns in Austria where they were married so I can search the churches for a marriage record.

Given that Alois was a coal miner, born in Austria and his wife born in Veliki Cirnik, what likely migration path would have taken him to meet his wife and get married in Austria before heading to Germany?

How might I locate common migration paths taken at this time to profile likely towns they got married in?

Comment: NB Slovenia / Styria WAS Austria before 1914 -- they may not have been far from home when they married. Banns should also have been published in their home towns, whereever they married.

Comment: @bgwiehle What are "Banns"?  Are they something I can find online?  Was german spoken in Austria in 1898?  Does the souvenir being written in German suggest a region?  Would the souvenir likely have been created when they got married or at a later time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banns_of_marriage - The trick is knowing the religious affiliation of the bride and groom and knowing a location. Yes German, and Hungarian, and Slovenian, and Czech and Slovak and a number of other languages were spoken in Austria and all its Crownlands before 1914. The souvenir would have been created for the wedding itself, the form of the gift may be regional. The language on the souvenir may have been the families' main language or it may have been intended to be universally understood among all the guests (using very basic words).